# Wrong OutPut with Vynograd Algorithm

Tags: c++

Please help me with algorithm. I'm trying to make Vinograd Algorithm and have output 0. The algorithm does not have to be maken with STL.
The problem I think is in creating col and row but I do not know how to repair it. I tried to find the problem with debugger but failed.

[image: Output]

The algorithm:

```
         d = b/2
               // rowFactors  Matr
                  for i  = 1 to a do
                rowFactor[i] = Matr[i, 1] * Matr[i, 2]
                for j = 2 to d do
                    rowFactor[i] = rowFactor[i] + Matr[i, 2j - 1] * Matr[i, 2j]
                end for j
            end for i
            // columnFactors Matr1
            for i = 1 to c do
                columnFactor[i] = Matr1[1,  i] * Matr1[2, i]
                    for j = 2 to d do
columnFactor[i] = columnFactor[i] + Matr1[2j - 1, i] * Matr1[2j, i]
                end for j
            end for i
             /Matr2
            for i = 1 to a do
                for j = 1 to c do
                    R[i, j] = -rowFactor[i] - columnFactor[j]
                    for k = 1 to d do
                        Matr2[i, j]=Matr2[i, j]+(Matr[i, 2k-1]+Matr[2k, j])*(Matr1[i2k]+Matr1[2k1,j])
                    end for k
                end for j
            end for i
```

My code:

```
int* col = new int[n];
            int* row = new int[n];
                int d = n / 2;
                for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
                {
                    col[i] = Matr[i][1] * Matr[i][2];
                    for (int j = 2; j < d; j++)
                    {
                        row[i] += Matr[i][2 * j - 1] * Matr[i][2 * j];
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
                {
                    col[i] += Matr1[i][1] * Matr1[i][2];
                    for (int j = 2; j < d; j++)
                    {
                        row[i] += Matr1[i][2 * j - 1] * Matr1[i][2 * j];
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 1; i < d; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
                    {
                    Matr[i][j] = -row[i] - col[j];
                        for (int k = 1; k < d; k++)
                        {
                            Matr2[i][j] += ((Matr[i][2 * k - 1] + Matr[2 * k][j]) * (Matr1[i][2 * k] + Matr1[2 * k - 1][j]));
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        cout << Matr2[i][j] << " ";

                    }
                    cout << endl;
                }

                system("pause");

            }
```

Comment: Are you aware that arrays start at index in C++? I believe you are looking at your matrix output. But I believe the algorithm given in the first snippet starts indexing with 1 (because this is usual in math and elsewhere). So, I guess you have to adjust your C++ implementation respectively. (I must admit that's just a shot into blue.)

Comment: Yet another shot into blue: In the algorithm (first snippet), it's e.g. `for i  = 1 to a do`. I believe this is a loop from 1 ... a (a inclusively). In C++, it's very usual to write the `for` loop with end exclusively: e.g. `for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)` because if `i` is an index of an array with size `n` then the loop must stop after `i = n - 1`, of course. However, if a loop from `m` to `n` (with `n` inclusive) is intended (i.e. `n` is the last value to iterate with) then nothing prevents you from writing `for (i = m; i <= n; ++i)`.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Vynograd Algorithm == [Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm)?

Comment: @Scheff thank you, yes it is this algorithm.